# How can I use flex or awk to automate translation of code from one programming language to another?

Tags: apache-flex, awk, code-translation

It should be noted that the structure of code of the two programming languages is different, as in, the way certain IF-ELSE statements are written is different and I need to scan through the first code completely to know variables to be declared in the second code beforehand.

Comment: Lets start with the assumption that this isn't trivial, source code transformations in general, let alone by just using flex or awk. What are your source and target languages?

Comment: Checkout cucumber: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki http://cukes.info/

Comment: Visual Fox Pro to T-SQL